# Langchain and RAG does not properly retrieve the parts of the document I need

Tags: python, langchain, llama

I'm using langchain and RAG with llama to answer questions based on a FAQ document. The document is in pdf format and is a list of numbered questions and answers. The code works perfectly, but the retrieval of information from the documents is not correct. Despite asking it the same question in the documents, langchain cannot retrieve the correct question and answer match, retrieving parts of the document that are similar but do not answer my question.

Here is my code:

```
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader

loader = PyPDFLoader("doc.pdf")
data = loader.load_and_split()

from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1500, chunk_overlap=100)
all_splits = text_splitter.split_documents(data)

# Embed and store
from langchain.embeddings import (
    GPT4AllEmbeddings,
    OllamaEmbeddings,  # We can also try Ollama embeddings
)
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma

vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents=all_splits, embedding=GPT4AllEmbeddings())

from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate

template = "..."

QA_CHAIN_PROMPT = PromptTemplate.from_template(template)# Run chain

# LLM
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManager
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler
import requests
import json

# QA chain
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA

qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm,
    retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(),
    return_source_documents=True,
    chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": QA_CHAIN_PROMPT}
)

question = "..."
print(qa_chain({"query": question}))
```

What am I doing wrong?
Can I improve something or use another technique?
Why doesn't it retrieve the right document question for me?

I thank everyone for any help

Comment: Never tried `GPT4AllEmbeddings`, but would recommend to try `embedding = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2")`

Comment: Thanks for the help. It actually works much better with hf. Are there any additional techniques to make text retrieval more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Post a code for your reference, which uses HuggingFace embedding model(s).

```py
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader, DirectoryLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.llms import OpenAI


loader = DirectoryLoader('/tmp/', glob="./*.pdf")    # copy any PDF to /tmp
documents = loader.load()

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000,
                                               chunk_overlap=100)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    # model_name="sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2")
    model_name="bert-base-multilingual-cased")

persist_directory = "/tmp/chromadb"
vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(documents=texts, embedding=embeddings, persist_directory=persist_directory)
vectordb.persist()


qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
        llm=OpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="text-davinci-003"),
        retriever=vectordb.as_retriever(), chain_type="stuff",
        # chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs,
        return_source_documents=True)

response = qa_chain("please summarize this book")
print(response)
```

If you want to use other **open-source** LLM, instead of OpenAI you can try

```py
llm = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id = "google/flan-t5-base",
                     model_kwargs={"temperature":0.6,"max_length": 500, "max_new_tokens": 200
                                  })
```

Or

```py
llm = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id="EleutherAI/gpt-neo-2.7B")
```